# Вызвать модальное окно без кнопки/ссылки

Tags: javascript

Есть модально окно.

```
<div class="remodal-bg">
    <a href="#modal">Click</a>
    <br><br>

    <div class="remodal" data-remodal-id="modal">
        <h1>Remodal</h1>
        <p>
            Flat, responsive, lightweight, fast, easy customizable modal window plugin
            with declarative state notation and hash tracking.
        </p>
        <p>
            Minified version size: ~4kb
        </p>
        <br>
        <a class="remodal-cancel" href="#">Cancel</a>
        <a class="remodal-confirm" href="#">OK</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Вот js скрипт - http://eventfull.ru/jquery.remodal.js

Вот как мне сделать, чтобы окно появлялось - если код есть на странице.

Answer (score 1):

Вот страница с описанием https://github.com/VodkaBears/Remodal#readme и на русском http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=32&id=2000

У них же в примерах указано, как вызвать окно без нажатия на кнопки и ссылки.
Чтобы это выполнялось сразу по загрузке страницы, сделайте так:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){ // когда страница загрузилась
    // найти модальное окно
    var inst = $.remodal.lookup[$('[data-remodal-id=modal]').data('remodal')];
    // открыть модальное окно
    inst.open();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Ой спасибо+)))

Comment: Но кстати не работает=)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/copist/n3taP/1/embedded/result/

а ещё можно нативно, через хэш-ссылки, без дополнительного кода javascript: https://github.com/VodkaBears/Remodal#hashtracking